# How to configure watchdog for the arduino Nano 33 BLE Sense board?

Tags: arduino, watchdog, nano, interruption

For the arduino Nano 33 BLE Sense board, the standard `avr/wdt.h` is not available. And it seems that no standard library provides it. How to use the watchdog system for this board ? I found no full information about it.

I've found the page https://www.mysensors.org/apidocs/group__avr__watchdog.html which allow to configure the reboot mode. And it works.
But no way to configure the interruption mode with `ISR()` function.
Moreover, there's no explanation about the manipulation of used register/variables for any fine configuration.

Simple code example with regular asynchronous stuff using the watchdog `ISR()` mechanism. It which works well with ATmega328 (e.g.UNO). But I do not find equivalent configuration for the Nano 33 BLE using the nRF52840.

```
# include <avr/wdt.h>

volatile byte led;
int k;

ISR(WDT_vect) {
  Serial.println("Asynchronous stuff in ISR() function");
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN,led);
  led=!led;
}

void setup() {
  pinMode(LED_BUILTIN,OUTPUT);  
  led=0;
  
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while(!Serial) {}
  Serial.println("== R E B O O T ==");

  WDTCSR = ( 1 << WDE ) | ( 1 << WDCE );
  WDTCSR = ( 1 << WDP2 ) | ( 1 << WDP0 ) | ( 1 << WDIE ) ; // Interruption and timeout  1/2 s
}

void loop() {
  Serial.print("Loop #");
  Serial.println(k);
  if (k++%2) {
    Serial.println("Some stuff (even branch)");
    delay(1200);
  }
  else {
    Serial.println("Some stuff (odd branch)");
    delay(4800);
  }
}
```

Thks.

Comment: It might help to know which device you are using.

Comment: It's the arduino Nano 33 BLE Sense board.

Comment: MCU is nRF52840 btw. You can configure ISR mode, but it only pospones reset by two 32k clocks. Also you have to configure it before writing 1 to start task register, after that it's blocked. What do you really want to archieve, do you even need wdt?

Comment: I've just added a simple code example which works for Uno. And I would like to have equivalent configuration with Nano BLE

Comment: As you mentioned `avr/wdt.h` there is an AVR Controller? No?

Comment: That's the point. In UNO, it's an AVR microcontroler. In the Nano BLE, it's a RF52840. And I'm looking for equivalent code for that microcontroler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, for the RF52940, I'm not sure that the watchdog can provide the needed interruption mechanism despite it exists the INTENSET bit for interruption according to the chipset doc https://content.arduino.cc/assets/Nano_BLE_MCU-nRF52840_PS_v1.1.pdf).
But the good way is for sure the use of timers (and one can use more than just one, quite good).

For a similar behaviour as the code given for the UNO before, here is the code one can write for the Nano BLE using a timer interrupt (see https://github.com/khoih-prog/NRF52_MBED_TimerInterrupt for full and usefull doc).

```
#include "NRF52_MBED_TimerInterrupt.h"

volatile byte led;
volatile uint32_t count=0;
NRF52_MBED_Timer myTimer(NRF_TIMER_1); 
unsigned k=0;

void myHandler() {
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN,led);
  led=!led;
  count++;
}

void setup() {
  pinMode(LED_BUILTIN,OUTPUT);  
  led=0;
  
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while(!Serial) {}
  Serial.println("== R E B O O T ==");

  if (myTimer.attachInterruptInterval(500*1000, myHandler)) // each 1/2 second
    Serial.println("myTimer launched");
  else
    Serial.println("Can not set the timer");
}

void loop() {
  Serial.print("Loop #");
  Serial.print(k);
  Serial.print(" and nb times in Handler : ");
  Serial.println(count);
  if (k++%2) {
    Serial.println("Some stuff (even branch)");
    delay(1200);
  }
  else {
    Serial.println("Some stuff (odd branch)");
    delay(4800);
  }
}
```